# Working with vectors, distances and graphs JAVA

Tags: java, vector, graph, distance

I am working with vectors in graphs.
The first part of the program generates a random position point of a vector on the graph.
Next, I want the program to generate another random position point of a vector on the graph. 
How do I generate the second position vector, keeping in mind that the distance between both position vectors has to be 1?

Answer (score 0):

1. Randomize an angle `x` between 0 and 360 (or between 0 and 2*PI if you use radians).
2. Add `cos(x)` to the x-value of the first random position point
3. Add `sin(x)` to the y-value of the first random position point
4. Profit :)

**Why?** Geometry. All the points on the circle `(cos(x), sin(x))` are always 1 unit length away from its center.

Comment: While writing the program I realized that your suggestion does not work completly since I am working with a 3 dimensional vector. Therefore I have to take into consideration the position of the z-axis when creating a distance of 1